# Select the 2 first words in a html tag and add a selector

Tags: jquery

I use this script to select the 1st word in a container:

```
$(".article-title").html(function(){
    var text= $(this).text().trim().split(" ");
    var first = text.shift();
    return (text.length > 0 ? "<span class='special'>"+ first + "</span> " : first) + text.join(" ");
});
```

How can I select the 2 or 3 first words?

Thank you

Comment: do you want words in separated lines or in the same line like a sentence?

Comment: I want to add a <span> .. </span> on the 1st 2 words

Comment: Can you show html example and expected result?

Comment: <div class="article-title"> this is: a title of the article</div>
I want the result: <div class="article-title"> <span>this is:</span> a title of the article</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way.

```
$(".article-title").html(function(){
    var text= $(this).text().trim().split(" "); //.split() returns an array.
    var first = text[0];
    var second = text[1];
    return (text.length > 0 ? "<span class='special'>"+ first + " " + second + "</span>" : first) + text.slice(2).join(" ");
});
```

**Edit:** As per comments.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyc6sdub/3/)

Comment: and how I will add a class or span on the 1st 2 words?

Comment: @geoplous..plz refer updated answer as per your need.

Comment: @Mohammad..as per my understanding what OP wants .. this fiddle is working fine...http://jsfiddle.net/hyc6sdub/1/

Comment: it is not worked well. Lets be exact: I want to have the 2 first words inside a class and all the rest as it is

Comment: @geoplous..happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

try this.. you can get First n Words From your paragraph

```js
$('.article-title').html(function (i, html) {
    return html.replace(/(\w+\s\w+)/, '<span>$1</span>')
});
```

```html
<div class="article-title"> this is: a title of the article</div> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want this:<div class="article-title"> this is: a title of the article</div>
to have this result: <div class="article-title"> <span>this is:</span> a title of the article</div> So the 1st 2 words to have a <span> </span>

Comment: Yes it is working now but I have already chosen the above answer as correct, thank you anyway.